# jqgrid TreeGrid unable to see content of expanded column

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jqgrid

I have problem while rendering expanded column text while using jQuery jqgrid's treegrid type. Here's my treegrid definition and the response from server, I'll be happy if someone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

**Javascript**

```
menuGrid.jqGrid({
    url:'kullanici/loadMenu.ajax', 
    //enable TreeGrid
    treeGrid: true,
    //set TreeGrid model
    treeGridModel: 'adjacency', //'nested', //'adjacency',
    //set expand column
    ExpandColumn: 'Text',
    width: 550,
    datatype: 'json',
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true,
    colNames: ['ID', 'Text'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 20, align: 'left', editable: false, key: true, sorttype:'int', hidden: false },
        { name: 'Text', index: 'menuName', width: 120, sortable: true, align: 'left' }
    ],
    jsonReader: { 
        repeatitems : false,
        id: 'id'
    },
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    height: 200,
    sortable: true,
    enabletooltips: true,
    caption: 'Menü Ağacı'
});
menuGrid.jqGrid('navGrid','#paddtree');
```

**The JSON response from server**

```
{"rows":[{"expanded":true,"id":1,"isLeaf":false,"level":0,"loaded":true,"text":"Kullanici Islemleri"},{"expanded":false,"id":2,"isLeaf":true,"level":1,"loaded":true,"parent":1,"text":"Kullanici Ekle"},{"expanded":false,"id":3,"isLeaf":true,"level":1,"loaded":true,"parent":1,"text":"Kullanici Duzenle"},{"expanded":false,"id":4,"isLeaf":true,"level":1,"loaded":true,"parent":1,"text":"Kullanici Sil"},{"expanded":true,"id":5,"isLeaf":false,"level":0,"loaded":true,"text":"Fatura ??lemleri"},{"expanded":false,"id":6,"isLeaf":true,"level":1,"loaded":true,"parent":5,"text":"Fatura Goruntule"}],"records":6,"success":true}
```

Comment: I have added the solution below..

Answer (score 0):

Your Json response must be as follows :

```
    {"rows":[
        {
        "id":1,
        "text":"Kullanici Islemleri"
        "level":0,
        "isLeaf":false,
        "parent" : "null" //If the row is at 0-lvl
        "expanded":true,
        "loaded":true,
        },
    ],"records":6,"success":true}
```

You have to respect the order of the grid cols.
First, your data cols, then, `level`,`isLeaf`, `parent`,`expanded`. I'm not sure about the `loaded` field, try with and without.

Comment: `loaded` field does the work to expand the tree node at first. As I know order of the data isn't important at all. I can see the value of other fields like ID. I just can't see the expand column value.

Answer (score 0):

OK,I have found the solution, `colNames`, `colModel` and `ExpandColumn` configs should match(**case-sensitive**). As I said above the order of config isn't important.